# How to open a file in an external program?

Tags: labview

All I want is to open a file, test.txt, in notepad and keep it open. Although, this is proving more difficult than I'd expect. I run the code and expect the file to open; however, nothing appears. I experimented with opening the file in the terminal but this will not work in the larger context of my program. Please point out the obvious if I'm missing it

Here's the block diagram

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you posted opens a file as a reference for read/write inside the LabVIEW program, not with notepad. To open it in notepad, you have to issue an `exec`, with System Exec.vi that launches `notepad.exe`, and give the file as an argument:

[image]

Also instead of looping on listening to the stop button, use an event loop, it's better when you'll write more complex code.